# How to apply a `style` for a chip in code?

Tags: android, android-chips

In my xml layout I have a chip group with a filter chips.

```
<android.support.design.chip.ChipGroup
    android:id="@+id/chipGroup"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.design.chip.Chip
        style="@style/myStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    .....

</android.support.design.chip.ChipGroup>
```

As there are a lot of filters it's seems to be reasonable to add them in code. The problem is that I need to apply `style` attribute to every chip.

**I tried:**

```
val chip = Chip(ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.myStyle))
binding.chipGroup.addView(chip)
```

*no effect*

```
val chip = Chip(context, null, R.style.myStyle)
binding.chipGroup.addView(chip)
```

*no effect*

I created `layout/filter_chip.xml` and put there a chip template

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.chip.Chip 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="@style/myStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

and I create it in code like this

```
val chip = inflater.inflate(R.layout.filter_chip, binding.chipGroup, false) as Chip   
binding.chipGroup.addView(chip)
```

*It works* and style is applied. But I'm asking myself if it's really the simplest way to achieve it. Do you know the better one?

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use [ContextThemeWrapper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ContextThemeWrapper.html) by creating the ContextThemeWrapper with the style you want then passing the themed context to the constructor of the chip.

Comment: He said he tried it, but there was no effect. I'm also facing this problem and nothing works.